# Add custom method to JsonFormat

Tags: scala, playframework

I have `case class` with score (sum of all review scores) and count (of reviews) of reviews

```
case class Rating(score: Long = 0L, count: Int = 0) {
   def total():Long = if (count == 0) 0L else score/count;
}
```

and I want to support the following json format for serialization

```
{
    "score": 100,
    "count": 11
}
```

and after deserialization

```
{
    "score": 100,
    "count": 11,
    "total": 9
}
```

So I want to calculate `total` and display it in deserialized json. In case of `Json.format[ClassRating]` `total` will be ignored. Help me please to solve this issue

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved this issue

```
case class Rating(score: Long = 0L, count: Int = 0) {
  def total: Long = if (count == 0) 0L else score / count
}

object Rating {
    def apply(score: Long, count: Int): Rating = new Rating(score, count)
    def unapply(x : Rating): Option[(Long, Int, Long)] = Some(x.score, x.count, x.total)
}

val classRatingReads: Reads[Rating] = (
    (JsPath \ "score").read[Long] and
    (JsPath \ "count").read[Int]
)(Rating.apply _)

val classRatingWrites: OWrites[Rating] = (
  (JsPath \ "score").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "count").write[Int] and
  (JsPath \ "total").write[Long]
)(unlift(ClassRating.unapply))
```